# Docx4j-ImportXHTML fails to underline text in italics

Tags: docx4j

When in html there is a mix of underlined text plus italics then the docx generated loses the underlining.

pom.xml dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Example snippet:

```
public class UnderlineTests {

    static final String TEST_STRING = "<html><body><p><em>Italics</em></p>" +
            "<p><strong>Bold</strong></p>" +
            "<p><u>Underlined</u></p>" +
            "<p><strong><em>BoldItalics</em></strong></p>" +
            "<p><u><em>ItalicsUnderlined</em></u></p>" +
            "<p><strong><u>BoldUnderlined</u></strong></p></body></html>";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, Docx4JException {

        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(PageSizePaper.A4, true);

        XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporterForContent = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporterForContent.convert(TEST_STRING, null));
        wordMLPackage.save(new File("test.docx"));
    }
}
```

The above produces a `.docx` result like:

[image: this]

Note that the `<p><u><em>ItalicsUnderlined</em></u></p>` paragraph is not underlined!

Any help please (I need to keep `<u>` tag since the `html` feeding is coming from `CKEditor`)?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you change the order of underline and italic tags it works! very very strange:

`<p><em><u>ItalicsUnderlined</u></em></p>`

the above works!!!